# Object.get() is not iterable

Tags: json, ajax, django, serialization

I have this view

```
def view_involved_people(request):
     schedule = request.POST['schedule']
     query = Schedule.objects.get(pk=schedule)

     serialized = serializers.serialize('json', query)

     data = {'people': serialized}

return JsonResponse(data)
```

It displays that the object is not iterable. I think it is because I am only getting one instance of the object. However, how can I prevent this error and get this data from the view?

I have tried using `.filter()` but when I call `data.attribute_name`, it does not display the value

Comment: You need to serialize the queryset. See the django docs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/serialization/

Comment: It does not matter if you use `.filter()` or `.get()`. There will always be only one result because you do it with the `pk` and that should hopefully return only one result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `filter` in you case:

```
def view_involved_people(request):
     schedule = request.POST['schedule']
     query = Schedule.objects.filter(pk=schedule)

     serialized = serializers.serialize('json', query)

     data = {'people': serialized}

     return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: But using filter does not let me access the attributes of the instance? How can I do such?

Comment: Where you want to access the attributes ? Maybe in your Ajax success ?